# Ionic deeplinking - Redirect to website if app is not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, deep-linking

Is there a way to redirect user to a website (or even better to Appstore) if he wants to open a deeplink, but the app is not installed?
So for example i want to send a html email with

```
<a href="myapp://page">Great app!</a>
```

This will ask you do you want to open this link with the app, but only if you have the app installed on your phone.

If you don't have it, safari says that link is not valid and no action is taken.

Comment: Android and iOS support deep / universal links which you could use: 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content

Comment: did you get the answer? I want to redirect the user to play store to download the app if user doesn't have it on their device

Comment: Yes using the cordova-plugin-deeplinks, but you need to setup the universal links and the assetlinks.json for android. Check their full documentation. The bundle id must be correct and other configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `cordova-plugin-deeplinks` is what you need.

https://github.com/e-imaxina/cordova-plugin-deeplinks